# I am getting error while writing to csv using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am want to write the to CSV but getting errors with this code
'''

```
with open('dataset3extract1.csv', 'w', newline='') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    with open('dataset3', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        for line in myfile.readlines():
            senttoken = re.findall(r'title\"\:\"(.*?)\,"', line)
            res = [idx for idx in senttoken if not re.findall("[^\u0000-\u05C0\u2100-\u214F]+", idx)]
            print(res)
            writer.writerows(res)
```

'''

Below is the error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0437' in position 280: character maps to <undefined>
```

From my observation, it got truncated when it is to write the below line

```
['Outfit Fixation : Celeb Style: luckymag.com\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n &lt;a href=http://www.constantaservice.net/ &gt;запчасти тойота&lt;/a&gt;"']
```

Comment: This type of error is raised when a character is not defined in the target encoding. Thus, you are probably not using UTF8 when writing the file. Can you retry to open your target with the correct encoding? You can check your default encoding with ``locale.getpreferredencoding()``

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. I just included this:                                                            with open('dataset3extract1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as writeFile: